# I cannot call show() after close() with matplotlib in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm new to Python (I used MATLAB before), and I find that I cannot call `show()` after close some figures by `close()`. My goal is closing figures freely and then show the rest plots at last. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

My system: Python 3.6 on Windows 10. The matplotlib version is 2.2.2. I run my code through Eclipse.

Here is the code:

```
# Original code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figA = plt.figure('aa')
figB = plt.figure('bb')
plt.close('aa')

plt.plot([2,3],[1,1],color='green')
plt.show()
```

When I run it, I get the following error in the Eclipse console.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\a project for testing dionysus\test_pythonPractice.py", line 26, in 
>       plt.show()
>
> File "C:\Users\hanlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 253, in show
>       return _show(*args, **kw)
>
> File "C:\Users\hanlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 208, in show
>       cls.mainloop()
>
> File "C:\Users\hanlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends_backend_tk.py", line 1073, in mainloop
>       Tk.mainloop()
>
> File "C:\Users\hanlin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 557, in mainloop
>       _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tk'

However, if I change the code to either of the following two versions, there is no error.

```
# Revised ver.1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figA = plt.figure('aa')
figB = plt.figure('bb')
plt.close('bb')

plt.plot([2,3],[1,1],color='green')
plt.show()
```

or

```
# Revised ver.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figA = plt.figure('aa')
figB = plt.figure('bb')
plt.close('aa')

plt.plot([2,3],[1,1],color='green')
plt.show(block=False)
plt.pause(3)
```

From revised ver.1, my guess is that `close()` only works on the last added figure. If we remove the previous figure, there will be an "empty" element in the list recording those figures. But this assumption violates the revised ver.2... Does anyone know why and how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Reproducible in Eclipse Neon/PyDev, matplotlib 2.2.2, Python 3.5, Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Also reproducible on Eclipse Neon/PyDev, matplotlib 2.2.2, Python 3.6.6, Win10. Seems PyDev is the culprit. I rarely use close, but noticed a strange behavior in relation to another question before.

Comment: I can also reproduce, however it's worth noting if I use a different backend, e.g. qt4Agg I do _not_ get the error

Comment: @Mr.T Interesting. I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows 10 with Pycharm

Comment: @Mr.T You say that you rarely use close. Do you know any other ways to walk around? I just need a way to close figures freely (but of course, this error is interesting since it contradicts to my intuition...).

Comment: @DavidG I change the import lines into
 
    **import matplotlib.pyplot as plt**
    **import matplotlib**
    **matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = "qt4agg"**

But the same error shows up. Is this the right way of switching the backend? BTW, what does "backend" mean?

Comment: @shl7 Yes that is the correct way, however you need to do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` **after** the other 2 lines, otherwise you _will_ still get the same error. (also need to make sure you have qt4 if you choose to use that one, there are others, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for explanations and a list of possible backends)

Comment: @Mr.T Update: I just run the _original code_ through cmd **py -3 test_pythonPractice.py**, and the same error shows up, so I guest it's not due to PyDev.

Comment: @shl7 I suggest you summarise the comments, i.e., which configurations evoke and prevent the error message, in the question. I retract that Qt4/Qt5 show the same error, because matplotlib pretended whysoever that it had been switched to another backend, while it hadn't. Instead, GTKCairo and WebAgg don't evoke the error. So the culprit seems to be the TkAgg backend - we could have guessed it from the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Mr.T and @DavidG, I figure it out. Now the code becomes

```
# Revised original code
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figA = plt.figure('aa')
figB = plt.figure('bb')
plt.close('aa')

plt.plot([2,3],[1,1],color='green')
plt.show()
```

The culprit is the backend (default: "TkAgg"), and I set it as "Qt5Agg" now. I install the package **pyqt5** by

```
pip install pyqt5==5.10.1
```

Note that the **pyqt5 version** needs to be 5.10.1. The latest one (5.11.2) would cause another error. For details, please read [the webpage](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7958/).